# Can a magus use item mastery feats with a weapon enhanced by the arcane pool class feature?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, class-feature

Starting at level 5, a magus can use her [arcane pool](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus#TOC-Arcane-Pool-Su-) to enhance a weapon she's wielding and add magic properties, including flaming, flaming burst, frost, icy burst, shock and shocking burst.

The [Weapon Evoker Mastery](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-mastery-feats/weapon-evoker-mastery-item-mastery/) feat is an item mastery feat that increases damage dealt by magic weapon properties that deal extra energy damage by spending a swift action at the beginning of a round.

Can a magus use the Weapon Evoker Mastery to increase the damage dealt by magic properties she adds on a weapon via her arcane pool ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RAW, yes.

According to the Weapon Evoker Mastery feat you link to, the weapon must do energy damage.  How it gets that damage is not mentioned.

As a GM, spending feat to get an extra 1d4 for an energy type that can be defended against while using a weapon with only a so-so BAB is not a game breaker.

Now, if they could get this going at 2nd level, I might raise an eyebrow.  However, at 5th level, there are many ways of achieving similar results.